# How to align these items in MiGLayout

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I'm trying to have two checkboxes be next to each other, maybe with a slight gap, but it is doing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b7kZ.png). I wanted to get some help to try and shift it over. Here is the MiGLayout parameters and the code for the checkboxes.

```
red.setLayout(new MigLayout("fillx, inset 0"));
```

```
JCustomCheckbox snorlax = new JCustomCheckbox(null, new Color(255, 255, 255), 1.5, "Catch both Snorlax", 2);
red.add(snorlax, "newline, grow, pad 0 " + sub2 + " 0 0");

JCustomCheckbox snorlax12 = new JCustomCheckbox(null, new Color(255, 255, 255), 1.25, "Route 12", 3);
red.add(snorlax12, "newline, grow, pad 0 " + sub3 + " 0 0");

JCustomCheckbox snorlax16 = new JCustomCheckbox(null, new Color(255, 255, 255), 1.25, "Route 16", 3);
red.add(snorlax16, "grow");
```